# Confusion about Site url and directory

Tags: urls, domain, site-url

I have installed my wordpress in root/mysubfolder
so my standard path is example1.com/mysubfolder (example1.com is the domain i have registered the webspace with)

Now i want the wordpress installation to work with example2.com (registered another domain)
Therefore i have set the redirect for example2.com to the folder mysubfolder in my webspace admin area

what do i have to change to get this to work?

i have tried this in the wp-config.php file:

```
define('WP_HOME','http:example2.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http:example2.com');
```

it works for the wp-admin and the homesite.. but if i click on a post the path is example2.com/post1 ..which doesn't work

Comment: Post path is correct (domainname/postname). It seems what you need is a permalink flush. You said `example2.com/post1` doesn't work, what is the error you get ?

Comment: The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. contact webmaster etc...

Comment: That's unusual. Is `example2.com/wp-admin/` works perfectly (i see u already said that, even though) ?

Comment: yes thats the case.. really strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i forgot to edit the .htacess in my folder... :) now everything works fine!

Comment: Please explain your solution with more details, so future visitors will know exactly what to do.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you will need to adjust the above code to the following:

```
define('WP_HOME','http:example2.com/yoursubfolder/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http:example2.com/yoursubfolder/');
```

Give that a try.

EDIT:
you are missing the slashes on the http also -

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example2.com/yoursubfolder/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example2.com/yoursubfolder/');
```

Comment: If i do that, nothing works anymore..

Comment: The strane thing in my opinion is: myexample2.com equals myexample1.com/mysubfolder... and if i set the home and siteurl to myexample2.com it should work?!

Comment: these values are also stored in the Database and may be overriding what is in your config file.  If you have access to the DB, have a look in the wp_options table and see what the home and site URL's are set to...

Comment: hm seems to be the same but i can't find the home value in the database

Comment: that is usually on the second page of the options table

Comment: Ordinarily, if your wordpress installation lives at example.com/folder/  then your site and home url's should be set to the same

Comment: Yes but i already have a website which belongs to example1...example1 has nothing to do with the site example2

Comment: I think I understand, you want example2.com to go to the same website as example1.com?

Comment: Ehm, my webspace is registered on example1.com so my wordpress installation which is in root/mysubfolder automatically belongs to example1.com/mysubfolder... However i want the website appear under example2.com

Comment: in the root of example2.com create / edit the .htaccess file and put the following code inside: Redirect 301 / http://example1.com/mysubfolder

Comment: the root of example2 is the same as example1.. so that won't work

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the myexample2.com to be the root of your WP installation? In other words:

```
http://myexample.com/subfolder = http://myexample2.com
http://myexample.com/subfolder/post1 = http://myexample2.com/post1
```

If that's the case, then you simply need to set your "Wordpress Site URL" and "Wordpress Address URL" to myexample2.com. Then in your hosting account point myexample2.com domain to myexample.com/subfolder. All my sites are hosted this way.

Comment: That is exactly what i have done, it isn't working though.. (only the post sites)

Comment: Check to make sure the URLs are correct in the WP dashboard, not just the config. When you type in the myexample2.com/post1, does the URL terminate at myexample.com or do you just get a 404?